# Getting started with PySide

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I decided to learn Python Gui development and, as PyQt is non-free, the choice was PySide for it. But, unlike PyQt, PySide doesn't have any tutorials or screencasts, just documentation useless for very beginners. I have no Qt experience, so even setting up development environment in Ubuntu is a problem. Could you advice something to learn from?

Comment: PyQt is free (GPL licence - if that ain't free, Linux ain't either!). It's just not free for commercial applications. But since you're a beginner, it'll take quite a while until you should think of making something people would pay for.

Comment: I thought it's a good idea to practice on a real project but you're right. By the way, it's going to be a donation-ware, not shareware. Where can I read about good license for dw?

Comment: License it under GPL only. Accept donations. If people like what you are doing, they will donate themselves.

Comment: But as discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715844/changing-open-source-software-to-divert-donations if there are more experienced programmer, he could add few features and get my donates, right?

Comment: PySide is mostly PyQt compatible, so you can use the PyQt documentation instead. Also, unless your app is very simple you'll find that you refer to the Nokia Qt documentation most of all.

Comment: @user225312 Read Stallman's [rationales.](http://www.gnu.org/gnu/thegnuproject.html)  Once you see where he's coming from, you might not mind someone else getting "your" donations.  If you are willing to profit from other's works, you have to be willing to let others to profit from yours. "On shoulders of giants", etc. Otherwise, pay for the PyQt license or start writing a lot of code from scratch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are going to just learn GUI development with Python, does PyQt not *being free* really matter?

And make sure you actually know the PyQt [license](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/license) before arriving at such a conclusion!

There a plethora of tutorials available for both. See the [official documentation](http://wiki.qt.io/PySide_Tutorials). Note that the basic stuff (signals and slots etc.) is the same.  What differs is mentioned [here](http://wiki.qt.io/Differences_Between_PySide_and_PyQt).

Comment: Well, I didn't mention I'm going to practice on a real gui app project, which will be released under non-GPL, that's my bad.

Comment: Then note the differences and follow the PyQt tutorials if you know some good ones and are able to follow. Making the transition should not be difficult.

Comment: Yes, I second learning PyQT first (that's what I've done). That can be difficult enough because the documentation isn't very good for it either. Definitely take a look at the examples directory.

Comment: Right, thanks a lot! Thanks for replies, starting PyQt right now :)

Answer (score 6):

I am not surprised that you couldn't find any tutorials at the time PySide was trying to get its first stable release ever. =) Now that [PySide 1.0.0 is released](http://www.pyside.org/2011/03/pyside-python-for-qt-1-0-released/), API is stable and bugs are ruled out, you can find [newbie and advanced PySide tutorials](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_Tutorials) with the [rest of documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/PySideDocumentation) and links to [other resources](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Category:LanguageBindings::PySide) at Qt Wiki.

Answer (score 3):

Learning Qt with Python is much easier than with C++ .
 Setting up development environment - They provide Qt Designer which is a really good option.   Just design the GUI and convert it using pyuic tool . No tutorials ? Check these out.

[Zetcode](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/)

[Tutorial with Designer](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~afedosov/qttut/)

[A Nice list of simple Tutorials](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/introduction-pyqt4/)

And u can try this book : Rapid GUI Programming with python and Qt . The Book's impressive.

Comment: Tutorial with Designer link is down.

Answer (score 2):

At the time zetcode didn't have a pyside tutorial I suppose but it's there now and very helpful.

http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial about setting up the tools, designing GUI, writing code and compiling PySide into stand-alone apps. It has code samples, screen shots and videos: 
[Kodekraft](http://mspadaru.wordpress.com/youtube-player/)