# How to learn PySide?

Tags: python, pyside

[Documentation](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySideDocumentation/) has very few of tutorials:

- Your first PySide application
- A simple clickable button tutorial
- Simple PySide dialog application
- Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide
- Using_Qt_Properties_in_PySide
- PySide_DBus_Integration
- PySide_Internationalization
- PySide_Pitfalls

...
and that's all.

What method is the best to learn PySide?

Comment: [**PySide tutorial**](http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/) by Jan Bodnar is what got me started very quickly.

Comment: Learn PyQt, then consider whether you really want/need PySide. It is very easy to convert from PyQt to PySide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Check the tutorials of the `Qt` documentation.
- Check [this tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/) (the first one you found by googling for `pyside tutorial`
- Check [these tutorials](http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Tutorials) for `PyQt` (the first link when you google `pyqt tutorial`
- Practice, practice, practice. You'll be surprise how easy it can be.

And of course [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234028/getting-started-with-pyside) is full of related questions that will help you.